# How to compare a date returned from the DB to a date (string or otherwise)?

Tags: f#

I have a big flinq query that returns, among many other things, a date a conversation was started. I'd like to return only conversations that were started after 1-1-2011.

I have something like this:

```
conversation.TimeOfInitiation > "1-1-2011"
```

but i'm getting this error:

> The type `System.Nullable<System.DateTime>` does not support the 'comparison' constraint. 
>       For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface

obvoiusly my naive approach did not succeed. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx

You have to get the value.  Nullable is basically a generic container that carries a value.